# How to knowif all tests have passed with mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I would like to know if it is possible to execute something if all my test files have passed with mocha.
Below: is my index.js file which is run by mocha (in order to get the order I want)

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const logger = require('../toolkits/logger');

//silent mode for testing
logger.transports.forEach((t) => (t.silent = true));

require("./broker.test");
require("./mongo.test");
require("./auth.test");
require("./meal.test");
require("./bowl.test");
```

I want to `process.exit(0)` if the tests passed (to integrate it into gitlab CI).

I succeded in check if a test hasn't passed by doing this :

```js
afterEach(function(){
   if (this.currentTest.state === "failed")
        process.exit(1);
})
```

But I can't detect if all the tests passed.
I can't just `process.exit(0)` after requiring all the tests because some of them are asynchronous.
Do you have an idea how I can do that?

**! Update !**

I found out that I could pass the --exit argument when running mocha from npm :

`mocha file --exit`

Comment: Do you even need to do that? If all passed, won't it already exit with code 0? So you only need to handle the failure case?

Comment: It doesn't exit with code 0, maybe because I import an expressjs app ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am accomplishing this with `Cypress` (which is built on top of `Mocha`). I believe this should all work for you, with the exception of the `cy.state('runnable')` - there's probably a different way you need to get the mocha runnable if you aren't using Cypress.

```
function isInErrorState(): boolean {
    const runnable = cy.state('runnable') as Mocha.Runnable;
    if (runnable.parent !== undefined) {
        const { parent: { tests } } = runnable;
        return tests.some((test) => test.state === 'failed');
    }
    return false;
}
```